# Chromium embedded within WPF app with webdriver attached

Tags: wpf, selenium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp, cefglue

I have quite unusual problem. I would like to embed Chromium inside WPF desktop app in a way that it has [webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) attached to is so I can execute operations from selenium against that embedded browser from the same application.

In other words, I would like to be able to control this embedded browser from the application using selenium (navigate, select elements, wait for elements, etc..)

From what I have found so far, it is possible to attach to [CEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) ([cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) or [cefglue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/overview)) using webdriver but it spawns new process for the browser from external executable which is not what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to run cef inside WPF application with selenium in described scenario ?

Comment: Can you attach selenium to the spawned process? Most probably you need to set SingleProcess = true.